# i need to post with enter key but have shift & enter key for new line

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("#post_text").keydown(function(e){
// Enter was pressed without shift key
if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    // prevent default behavior
    e.preventDefault();
} 
if (e.keyCode == 13 && !e.shiftKey) {
alert('test');
}

});
```

i need something that functions like this, i need to post with the enter key but create new lines with the shift and enter key. just like the facebook message system.

Comment: http://craig.is/killing/mice - A simple library for handling keyboard shortcuts in Javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to consider the `shiftKey` value in both conditions.

```
$("#post_text").keydown(function(e){
    if (e.which === 13) {
        // Enter was pressed
        if (e.shiftKey) {
            // With shift
        }
        else {
            // Without shift
        }
    }
});
```

Also note the use of `which`, not `keyCode`. jQuery standardizes the event object, making sure `which` is set on browsers that don't set it.